# What is the "Instinct" tag for?

Tags: discussion, tags

We've got [instinct](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/instinct), and I honestly have no idea what it's for or what the intent of the tag is.  Two questions (one recently) were tagged with it.  There is currently no tag wiki definition.

Embellish it and keep it, or should I follow my own instinct and let it go the way of the dodo?

Answer (score 2):

I read it as being about the natural subconscious reactions and tendencies of our pets playing a role in the question or answer, hence the reason I applied it to the one question. I'm not wedded to it though.

To clarify, I see this as being distinguished from "behavior" in that instinct is about species tendencies and behavior is about individual pets within.